# display exception.ToString in error page ASP Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webforms

in error page ASP Web Form, we see some information about an error like Source, Browser, IP, UserID, Error in(page.aspx), Error Message, Stack Trace

how to also see the exception.ToString on this page?

[image]